# Insignificant Variables Panel data

Tags: regression, least-squares, panel-data

I am doing an analysis abut bank's performance between two types of banks(conventional and islamic), I have 250 observations(5 years, 50 banks) which makes it a panel data. the problem is that when running the regression analysis for each type of bank, I get all the variables are insignificant. I tried pooled OLS, random, fixed, but Nada. I really need some help. the variables have been chosen correctly, my literature review shows significance between the dependent variables chosen and the independent. The variables are all ratios/percentages.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How does your response look like? Your, prossibly, trying to fit a linear model to something that's highly non-linear